# Finding specific ideals of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

How does one go about finding all the ideals of a ring (quadratic extension) containing a specific number?
In particular find all the ideals of $\mathbb Z(\sqrt{-29})$ which contain the integer 30.

Comment: What do you know about quadratic number rings? Do you know that its the full ring of integers, that contains = divides for ideals, and how primes split?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha$ represents the square root of a negative integer, so that we may think of $R=\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ as a subset of the complex plane. The following Proposition will make our task a great deal simpler (though its proof is non-trivial).

**Lemma 1**: Suppose $a+bi,c+di$ with $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$, $i^2=-1,$ and $a,b$ not both zero. Then $c+di$ is a real multiple of $a+bi$ if and only if $ad-bc=0$. [I leave the proof to you.]

**Lemma 2**: Suppose $a+bi,c+di$ with $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ and $ad-bc\neq 0$. Then for any $x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb R$, there exist unique $\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R$ such that $x+yi=\beta(a+bi)+\gamma(c+di).$ [I leave the proof to you.]

**Lemma 3**: Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are as in Lemma 2. Then for any real $x_1,x_2$, we have $$|x_1(a+bi)+x_2(c+di)|\leq |x_1||a+bi|+|x_2||c+di|,$$ with equality only if $x_1=x_2=0$. [I leave the proof to you.]

**Proposition**: If $I$ is an additive subgroup of $\langle R,+\rangle$, then exactly one of the following is true:

> (i) $I=\{0\}$.
>
> (ii) There exist $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ not both zero such that $$I=\{km+kn\alpha:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$$
>
> (iii) There exist $m_1,n_1\in\Bbb Z$ not both zero and $m_2,n_2\in\Bbb Z$ not both zero, such that $m_1n_2-m_2n_1\neq 0$ and $$I=\{j(m_1+n_1\alpha)+k(m_2+n_2\alpha):j,k\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

**Proof of Proposition**:

${}\quad{}$It is clear that (i) and (ii) can't both happen, and that (i) and (iii) can't both happen. I leave it to you to show that if (ii) happens, then (iii) *can't* happen, so (ii) and (iii) can't both happen, either. Hence, **at most** one of conditions (i) through (iii) may hold. It remains to show that **at least** one holds.

${}\quad{}$Suppose that neither (i) nor (ii) holds, so that we need only show (iii) holds. Note that if $m+n\alpha\in I$ is non-zero--and since (i) fails to hold, there is at least one such $m+n\alpha\in I$--then $|m+n\alpha|^2=m^2-n^2\alpha^2$ is a positive integer (since $\alpha^2$ is a negative integer, and $m$ and $n$ are integers not both zero). Hence, there exist $m_1,n_1\in\Bbb Z$ not both zero such that $m_1+n_1\alpha\in I$ and such that $|m_1+n_1\alpha|^2\leq|m+n\alpha|^2$ for all non-zero $m+n\alpha\in I$. Now, since (ii) doesn't hold, then there exist $m+n\alpha\in I\setminus\{km_1+kn_1\alpha:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$ In particular, there exist $m_2,n_2\in\Bbb Z$ such that $m_2+n_2\alpha\in I\setminus\{km_1+kn_1\alpha:k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and such that $|m_2+n_2\alpha|^2\le|m+n\alpha|^2$ for all $m+n\alpha\in I\setminus\{km_1+kn_1\alpha:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$

${}\quad{}$Now, if $m_1n_2-m_2n_1=0,$ then since $\alpha=i\sqrt{-\alpha^2}$ we have by Lemma 1 that there is a real number $x$ such that $m_2+n_2\alpha=x(m_1+n_1\alpha),$ and since $m_2+n_2\alpha\notin\{k(m_1+n_1\alpha):k\in\Bbb Z\},$ then $x$ is not an integer, and so there is an integer $j$ such that $j<x<j+1$. Since $m_2+n_2\alpha=x(m_1+n_1\alpha),$ then $$|j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-(m_2+n_2\alpha)|^2=|(j-x)(m_1+n_1\alpha)|^2=|j-x|^2|m_1+n_1\alpha|^2.\tag{#}$$ Since $j<x<j+1$, then $0<x-j<1$, so $0<|j-x|<1$, so $0<|x-j|^2<1$, and so since $|m_1+n_1\alpha|\neq 0,$ it follows from $(\#)$ that $$0<|j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-(m_2+n_2\alpha)|^2<|m_1+n_1\alpha|^2.\tag{##}$$ But $j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-(m_2+n_2\alpha)\in I,$ so $(\#\#)$ contradicts our choice of $m_1+n_1\alpha.$ Hence, we must have $m_1n_2-m_2n_1\neq 0$.

Finally, we show that $I=\{j(m_1+n_1\alpha)+k(m_2+n_2\alpha):j,k\in\Bbb Z\},$ so that (iii) holds. We already know that $I\supseteq\{j(m_1+n_1\alpha)+k(m_2+n_2\alpha):j,k\in\Bbb Z\}$ since ideals are additively closed. Take any $m+n\alpha\in I$. By Lemma 2, there exist unique $\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R$ such that $$m+n\alpha=\beta(m_1+n_1\alpha)+\gamma(m_2+n_2\alpha).$$ We wish to show that $\beta,\gamma$ are integers. By way of contradiction, suppose not. Since $\beta,\gamma$ are real non-integers, then there exist integers $j,k$ such that $0<|\beta-j|\le\frac12$ and $0<|\gamma-k|\le\frac12$. Then since $|m_1+n_1\alpha|^2\le|m_2+n_2\alpha|^2$ implies $|m_1+n_1\alpha|\leq|m_2+n_2\alpha|,$ we have $$\begin{align}|m+n\alpha-j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-k(m_2+n_2\alpha)| &= |(\beta-j)(m_1+n_1\alpha)+(\gamma-k)(m_2+n_2\alpha)|\\ &< |\beta-j||m_1+n_1\alpha|+|\gamma-k||m_2+n_2\alpha|\\ &\le \frac12|m_1+n_1\alpha|+\frac12|m_2+n_2\alpha|\\ &\le |m_2+n_2\alpha|,\end{align}$$ where the strict inequality comes from Lemma 3. Since $m+n\alpha-j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-k(m_2+n_2\alpha)\in I$ by additive closure, it then follows from our choice of $m_2+n_2\alpha$ that $m+n\alpha-j(m_1+n_1\alpha)-k(m_2+n_2\alpha)$ is an integer multiple of $m_1+n_1\alpha$. But then $m+n\alpha-k(m_2+n_2\alpha)=\beta(m_1+n_1\alpha)+(\gamma-k)(m_2+n_2\alpha)$ is an integer multiple of $m_1+n_1\alpha,$ so $(\gamma-k)(m_2+n_2\alpha)$ is, too. Since $m_2+n_2\alpha$ isn't an integer multiple of $m_1+n_1\alpha$, it follows that $\gamma=k$ (so $\gamma$ is an integer), but then $\beta(m_1+n_1\alpha)$ is an integer multiple of $m_1+n_1\alpha,$ whence $\beta$ is an integer. Thus, assuming that $\beta,\gamma$ not both integers leads to the desired contradiction. $\Box$

---

The above Proposition has a tremendous upside for you in the case that $\alpha=\sqrt{-29}$, since ideals are necessarily additive subgroups of $\langle R,+\rangle$. It remains to you to see under what conditions the additive subgroups of type (i) through (iii) can be ideals--you'll need to confirm which have the property that $x\in I$ and $r\in R$ implies $r\cdot x\in I$--then figure out which ideals (if any) of each type have $30$ as an element.