# Subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is from a qualifying exam I found and I was wondering if I found all the subrings possible.  The question was:

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the set of complex numbers of the form $a + bi$ where $a$ and $b $ range over all integers. List all subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. (Your list should contain each subring exactly once.)

So obviously, $\{0\}$, and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are subrings.  I also believe the following are subrings; $\mathbb{Z},k\mathbb{Z}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $k\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  They are all definitely additive commutative groups, and closed under multiplicaiton and distribution...I'm I missing any other subgroups?

Comment: If you require that a ring has identity, then $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are not rings unless $k=0$ or $k=1$.

Comment: And if you don't require that a ring have a multiplicative identity, you are missing $\alpha{\bf Z}[i]$, $\alpha$ in ${\bf Z}[i]$. Oh, and this marks the first time I've ever seen a qualifying exam tagged recreational-mathematics.

Comment: The question didn't say ring with unit, so i assumed it was not the case...

Comment: @Christopher: What is your definition of a subring (precisely)? There are several conventions (unfortunately).

Comment: It's just posted on my old university website and it was recreational for me...I'll remove the tag!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I was using Herstein's Abstract Algebra definition which is an abelian additive group, closed under multiplication, multiplication is associative, and the two distributive laws.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, by $\alpha$, you mean from $\alpha+\beta{i}$?

Comment: No, by $\alpha$ in ${\bf Z}[i]$, I mean $\alpha$ in ${\bf Z}[i]$.

Comment: Oh, $\alpha$ is a complex integer...got it...

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/337064/28900).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly notice that any $Z$-module is free, the subring should have form $na$ or $na+mb$ or $\{0\}$.

In first case we have $a^2=na$, this gives $kZ$.

In second case we have $a^2=n_1a+m_1b$ ,$ab=n_2a+m_2b$ and $b^2=n_3a+m_3b$. Notice that this is sufficient. And for any $a,b\in Z[i]$ we can find $n$ big enough that $na,nb$ satisfies such condition. This finished the classification of Subrings of $Z[i]$. I think this can be further simplified considering $Z[i]^2/SL(2,Z)$

If you want the subring always contain identity, things were easier. In the first case only $Z$, second case only rings generated by $1$ and $ni$.

Comment: How did you arrive at your answer @Belanov?

Comment: @DonLarynx  The problem is equivalent with finding a set that closed with respect to multiplication and addition. And the trick to this sort of problem is to find a smaller set that generates them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since we are talking about a ring w/o unit under the definition of a ring as an abelian additive group closed under multiplication satisfying associativity and distribution, I think I've got the subrings as:

$\{0\}, \mathbb{Z}, k\mathbb{Z}, \alpha\mathbb{Z}[i],$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: If you want to list each subring just once, you'll have to weed out some duplicates.

Comment: So I can just say $k\mathbb{Z}$ and drop $\mathbb{Z}$ since that is the case where $k=1$

Comment: Huh? My point was, you can have (for example) $\alpha{\bf Z}[i]=\beta{\bf Z}[i]$ even though $\alpha\ne\beta$.

Comment: I can do the same with $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\alpha\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: You are forgetting actual subrIngs like $$\mathbb{Z}[ki]=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z},k\mid b\},$$ for some parameter $k>1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, so how do we distinguish then between such subrings as to only list them once?

Comment: Well, first you have to work out how such duplication can occur. It implies $\alpha=\beta\gamma$ and $\beta=\alpha\delta$ for some $\gamma$ and some $\delta$. But that implies $\gamma\delta=1$. So you have to think about how that can happen.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Aren't the only subrings $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Don, apparently not, e.g., wouldn't you agree that the set of all $a+2bi$, $a$ and $b$ integers, is a subring?

Comment: @GerryMyerson So our only subrings are $\mathbb{Z}[ki]$ and $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ correct?

Comment: @Don, ${\bf Z}/k{\bf Z}$ is not even a subset of ${\bf Z}[i]$, much less a subring.